# How to loop in canvas js to make a multiple series chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, charts

I am trying to make a multiple series chart using Canvasjs. My problem is I can't make a loop inside the dataPoints so I hardcoded everything. Is there a way I can user for loops?

Here is the Json data:

`[{"name":"Grace","label":"A","y":0},{"name":"Grace","label":"B","y":3},{"name":"Grace","label":"C","y":0},{"name":"Grace","label":"D","y":0},{"name":"Mirriam","label":"A","y":0},{"name":"Mirriam","label":"B","y":5},{"name":"Mirriam","label":"C","y":2},{"name":"Mirriam","label":"D","y":0},{"name":"Mar","label":"A","y":0},{"name":"Mar","label":"B","y":5},{"name":"Mar","label":"C","y":2},{"name":"Mar","label":"D","y":0},{"name":"Jejomar","label":"A","y":0},{"name":"Jejomar","label":"B","y":5},{"name":"Jejomar","label":"C","y":2},{"name":"Jejomar","label":"D","y":0}]`

Here is my code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 $(document).ready(function () {

$.getJSON('data.php', function (result) {
    var chart1 = new CanvasJS.Chart('Container', {
    title:{
        text: 'Results of Survey',
    },
    data: [

    {
        type: 'column',

        dataPoints: [
        { label:"A", y: result[0].y},
        { label:"B", y: result[1].y},
        { label:"C", y: result[2].y},
        { label:"D", y: result[3].y},
        ]

    },{
        type: 'column',
        dataPoints: [
        { label:"A", y: result[4].y},
        { label:"B", y: result[5].y},
        { label:"C", y: result[6].y},
        { label:"D", y: result[7].y},
        ]

    },{
        type: 'column',
        dataPoints: [
        { label:"A", y: result[8].y},
        { label:"B", y: result[9].y},
        { label:"C", y: result[10].y},
        { label:"D", y: result[11].y},
        ]
    },{
        type: 'column',
        dataPoints: [
        { label:"A", y: result[12].y},
        { label:"B", y: result[13].y},
        { label:"C", y: result[14].y},
        { label:"D", y: result[15].y},
        ]
    }

    ]




});

chart1.render();

});


});

 </script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <div id="Container" style="width: 800px; height: 380px;"></div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var persons = {}
json.forEach(d => {
  if (!(d.name in persons)) persons[d.name] = []
  persons[d.name].push({label: d.label, y: d.y})
})

var data = Object.keys(persons).map(name => {
  return {type: 'column', dataPoints: persons[name]}
})
```

First we take all the data points and group them by name. Then we construct the final data array by mapping over the names of the persons.